# Некорректное отображение шрифта с google-fonts

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты, google-fonts

Возникает проблема которая при подключении шрифта с google fonts шриф отображается некорректно. И не важно какой именно шрифт.
Например возьмём шрифт Montserrat.
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap
При подключении внутри тега head или внутри css ничего не меняется. В браузере любой выгруженный шрифт отображается мелким и тонким начертание. Смена языка ничего не меняет.
Пожалуйста если вы сталкивались с такой проблемой помогите решить его и понять в чем дело.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Хочу добавить, что если отдельно выгружать каждое начертание:

Comment: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: То так уже нормально работает. Однако это конечно не лучшее решение